Will silicon adhere to epoxied fiberglass tank
I use water retention tanks withs inner shell of blow molded HDPE and outer shell of wrapped fiberglass/epoxy.
The tanks get UV damage pretty quickly.
Will silicone coating adhere to the outershell?
Is there a better solution?

Wrap in aluminium foil... silicon is guaranteed to stick .... wherever it won't be needed. What about UV resistant paint?
